# Object with generic keys in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'd like to create a common function which will take an object, then do some transformations and return new object with same keys and different values. I'm trying to make it "strongly-typed", so everyone who uses it will have benefits of TS and non-existing keys should throw an error.

What I have for now:

```
const hash = {
  "first": 1,
  "second": 2,
  "third": 3,
}

type Mapper<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: number
}

type Result<T>= {
  [key in keyof T]: () => number
}

const transform = <T>(mapper: Mapper<T>) => {
  const result = {} as Result<T>

  (Object.keys(mapper) as (keyof T)[]).map(key => {
    result[key] = () => mapper[key]
  })

  return result
}

type Hash = typeof hash

const a = transform<Hash>(hash)

a.first()
// a.fifth() OK error
```

It works well, but I'm looking for solutions to solve this:

1. Remove type assertion `const result = {} as Result<T>`
2. Remove type assertion `(Object.keys(mapper) as (keyof T)[])` (or use `Object.entries`, but seems it also requires type assertion in this case)

Could I implement the same, but in more "clean" way in Typescript?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Object.keys` returns **always** `string[]` therefore you will need the casting.

A smaller & more robust version would use `Object.fromEntries`.
Another small improvement would be to use the type of the original key, with `T[Key]`.

```typescript
const hash = {
  "first": "someString",
  "second": 2,
  "third": 3,
};

type Result<T>= {
  [Key in keyof T]: () => T[Key]
};

const transform = <T extends object>(obj: T): Result<T> => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.keys(obj).map(
        (key) => [key, () => obj[key as keyof T]]
    )
  ) as Result<T>;
}

const a = transform(hash);

const first = a.first(); // returns "string"
//    ^? const first: string
const second = a.second(); // return "number"
//    ^? const second: number
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/MYewdgzgLgBAFgQwnGBeGBvAUDGAiAMwEsAnaPALnwhAFsBTAZShKLAHM8AaHa+0MABNKMAEw9ceKHFLCqAZh4BfANxYsUAJ4AHejABK9CAFcANlAA8AFQB86bLgDaAaXqaYbGAGs3IAjCsAXSoACgBKNBsAlzdArFV1AWgYFgRIAhASWjQYaxh6AA8oeiEIGBAAIwArfigbEMqqqiswqkMTc2so1CiHGBJ6KGMSMBgAeWragDoCEjoAUTAWIiMQ3lwJmuAoKZ9NCAbqsKnaBG013EvLkL2InphHPa4YcMjy6se3GCRvX38guJXMK8CI-dpmSy2NRKRLgZIIHKpdKZWghRDIMJqLBJWDEMiwdAIGakaDhFQwAD0FP6g2GkGoyw4eCwVKuAD0APzYuGwCD8cCCHJEvkCQRkynUgZDEb4MDGWgVegkZmsy6coA)

Comment: What the heck who could think changing `:` to `in` would fix that?Thanks!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Changed it to more elegant / modern solution, Object.fromEntries (which is much faster BTW)

Comment: @felixmosh - Nice! There was a typo in the code, so I went ahead and fixed it and formatted the code so it would cause horizontal scrolling, and added TypeScript playground link. Happy coding!